# Match variable part of a string with Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a word within a string as follow:

Example: "This is the string and I want to match varstring_const with regex."

I want to match varstring with a variable amount of letters.

I tried: [a-zA-Z].+_const

But this includes the whole left side of the string from "This is ...". But I only want to have the variable part of the word with _const.

I think I need something like a stopper at the end of the string. But in left direction.

Comment: What should be matched in your example exactly, and what programming language is used?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I think, something went wrong posting the question. I edited it, now it should be clear. I want to match varstring and I use javascript for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
[a-zA-Z]+   # Match 1+ letters
(?=_const)  # which is followed by '_const'
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/r2N8n7/1).

If you also need the `_const` part:

```
[a-zA-Z]+_const
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/r2N8n7/2).